# Pass tuple parameters to smart contracts using web3.py

Tags: python, web3py

I am using web3.py to pass a tuple type parameter to the contract smart,

```
   {'considerationToken': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'considerationIdentifier': 0, 'considerationAmount': 1950000000000000, 'offerer': '0xf6d4434b802877d7f17c3383ce0deeef85b3a1eb', 'zone': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'offerToken': '0x3203203Db85E0980e3E08A1Aac083FC4DECF6EDA', 'offerIdentifier': 2, 'offerAmount': 1, 'basicOrderType': 2, 'startTime': 1665136887, 'endTime': 1667815287, 'zoneHash': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'salt': '0x360c6ebe00000000000000000000000000000000000000003f4e9ce90a9dc88a', 'offererConduitKey': '0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000', 'fulfillerConduitKey': '0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000', 'totalOriginalAdditionalRecipients': 1, 'additionalRecipients': [{'amount': 250000000000000, 'recipient': '0x0000a26b00c1f0df003000390027140000faa719'}], 'signature': '0x47d29ea6aadde9ce7b3a2c6f3cce560697200b103be114747e453e0989f42d7360a40a4e62941371549be78fe00232ea6c407d20346bb0811ed6610513b338fb1c'}
```

This is the parameter I generated, which can be used normally in `etherscan, but an error is reported in the function,
Below is my code.

```
basic_order_parameters = {
"considerationToken": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"considerationIdentifier":0,
"considerationAmount":1950000000000000,
"offerer": "0xf6d4434b802877d7f17c3383ce0deeef85b3a1eb",
"zone": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"offerToken": "0x3203203Db85E0980e3E08A1Aac083FC4DECF6EDA",
"offerIdentifier":2,
"offerAmount":1,
"basicOrderType": 2,
"startTime": 1665136887,
"endTime": 1667815287,
"zoneHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"salt": "0x360c6ebe00000000000000000000000000000000000000003f4e9ce90a9dc88a",
"offererConduitKey": "0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
"fulfillerConduitKey":"0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
"totalOriginalAdditionalRecipients": 1,
"additionalRecipients": additionalRecipients3,
"signature": "0x47d29ea6aadde9ce7b3a2c6f3cce560697200b103be114747e453e0989f42d7360a40a4e62941371549be78fe00232ea6c407d20346bb0811ed6610513b338fb1c"
}
```

This is the error message

```
web3.exceptions.ValidationError:
Could not identify the intended function with name `fulfillBasicOrder`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'dict'>,)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `fulfillBasicOrder`: ['fulfillBasicOrder(tuple)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

This is the smart contract address: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00000000006c3852cbef3e08e8df289169ede581

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The error said you are trying to use Dict instead of Tuple.

Did you try it like this?

```
myContract.functions.fulfillBasicOrder(
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    0,
    1950000000000000,
    "0xf6d4434b802877d7f17c3383ce0deeef85b3a1eb",
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "0x3203203Db85E0980e3E08A1Aac083FC4DECF6EDA",
    2,
    1,
    2,
    1665136887,
    1667815287,
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "0x360c6ebe00000000000000000000000000000000000000003f4e9ce90a9dc88a",
    "0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
    "0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
    1,
    additionalRecipients3,
    "0x47d29ea6aadde9ce7b3a2c6f3cce560697200b103be114747e453e0989f42d7360a40a4e62941371549be78fe00232ea6c407d20346bb0811ed6610513b338fb1c"
)
```